# I need function to change image file name when website language is changed

Tags: php, image, filenames

I use code:

```
<img src="images/english.png"/>
```

My site use 2 language English and Vietnamese, I want when change language to Vietnamese, the image filename will be change to vietnamese.png example:

```
<img src="images/vietnamese.png"/>
```

have already 2 image file into images folder, i need PHP script for change it when change language

Answer (score 0):

create an if else statement. When you select for example English, show image A, else show image B. What happens is when you select a language, you most likely change a value. So use that value to create an if else statement, that has to correspondent with you image.

Its really easy if you ask me. I put an example here below

```
if($LanguageVar == 1)
    { 
        Echo "<img src='blablaba1.png'></img>";
    }
    else
    {
        Echo "<img src='blablaba2.png'></img>";
    }
```

or something in that general direction

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide some more information than that- for example, how does your site determine which language to use?

Assuming that you can create a boolean value in PHP (let's call it langV) that is true if the language is Vietnamese, and false if it's English, then here's all you have to do:

Replace your img tag:

```
<img src="e_image" alt=""/>
```

With something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo langV?:'v_image''e_image' ?>" alt=""/>
```

Replacing v_image and e_image with the paths to your separate image files, of course.

Answer (score 0):

How does your website know which language is being used?

You can use parts of the URL. For example, if you have

```
http://www.mysite.com/viet/
http://www.mysite.com/en/
```

name your images "viet.png" and "en.png"

```
$lang = end(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'))

<img src="$lang.png" />
```

It really depends on how the site determines which language to use

Answer (score 0):

Set Cookie value For language

When User Select Language

```
<?php
$value = 'en';
setcookie("lan", $value);
setcookie("lan", $value, time()+3600); 
?>
```

For Generating Image

```
<?php
if($_COOKIE['lan']=='en'){
echo "<img src='blablaba1.png'></img>";
}
else{
echo "<img src='blablaba2.png'></img>";
}
```